# Crashing when loading zip using cocos2d-x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have a problem using cocos2d-x on android.
I am trying to load a .zip file using

```
CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileDataFromZip(...)
```

As this project is designed to be multiplatform, we also tried this code on an iPad3 and there it is working without problem.
The problem is that the app gets an Segmentation Fault when loading the zip file.

Here is the whole code with some extra comments

```
void Map::loadChunk(int index, CCPoint startPoint) {
    chunks[index]->startPoint = startPoint;
    std::stringstream filename;
    filename << (int)startPoint.x << "_" << (int)startPoint.y << ".map";

    unsigned long filesize = 0;
    const char* path = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathFromRelativePath("map1.zip");

    CCLog(path);
    CCLog(filename.str().c_str());

    // In the following two lines the error occurs
    const char* buffer =(const char*) CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileDataFromZip(path, filename.str().c_str(), &filesize);    
    std::istringstream fileBuffer(buffer);


    CCLog("filesize %d", (int)filesize);
    std::string line;

    // Here some code follows but this code does not produce the problem so I left it out

}
```

The used includes are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

#include "cocos2d.h"
```

The values for **path** and **filename** are
**map1.zip** and **-128_-128.map**

map1.zip is in the assets folder and the .map file exists inside map1.zip

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out why this is not working.

It seems to be the problem to pack another .zip into the .apk.
When playing the .zip in the folder received by

```
CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWriteablePath()
```

and then open the zip with

```
CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileDataFromZip(...)
```

the zip loads properly and I am able to read certain files from inside the zip.